# ¿Cómo guardar un .pdf generado en un servidor diferente al servidor que lo genero?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un código que crea y guarda un .pdf en el servidor `192.188.78.4` y por motivos ajenos a mi voluntad me piden que lo guarde en `192.188.78.9`, es posible hacer eso? el servidor web es el `(...)78.4` y se debe guardar en otra aplicación alojada en el `(...)78.9`

```
 public void guardar_GenPDF()
    {// este es el 192.188.78.4
      string path="D:\\Hosting\\PDFs\\Datagen_" + lastIdenty + ".pdf";
    }
```

Comment: De poder se puede. Ahora bien, ¿tienes una aplicacion para recibir los archivos? ¿o es por ftp que lo deseas enviar?

Comment: Sí, en el otro servidor existe otra aplicación web que tienen acceso los funcionarios y cree una gemela donde tendrán acceso los clientes y cualquier visitante que ingrese por la web, entonces como los funcionarios pueden crear este pdf la idea es que el cliente si lo desea también lo pueda hacer, y el problema es que estan en 2 servers diferentes. Nota, los dos son Windows server con ISS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto en tu mensaje, estás trabajando con servidores Windows. Esto implica que si compartes en el servidor de destino la ruta en que deseas guardar los pdfs, se podría cambiar la ruta de destino por la que quede compartida...
Es decir, si el servidor 192.188.78.9 es un servidor Windows, y la carpeta en que deseas que queden los archivos compartidos la compartes con el nombre PDFs, podrías modificar tu path en el código para que quede algo así como:

```
 public void guardar_GenPDF()
    {// este es el 192.188.78.4
      string path=@"\\192.188.78.9\PDFs\Datagen_" + lastIdenty + ".pdf";
    }
```

Es necesario considerar que debes asignar los permisos adecuados para que la aplicación ejecutándose en el server que genera los archivos tenga permisos para escribir en la carpeta compartida.

Comment: Muchas gracias compadre, justo por ahí es que era la solución, ya estuve jugando con las carpetas compartidas y aunque no he logrado que el server .4 me guarde en el .9, si logré que el .9 lea el archivo desde el .4, seguiré investigando si la idea original es posible, si no es así al menos ya hay un plan B.